# if I want to distinguish the big spot, which specific algorithm should I try?

Tags: opencv

[image]

if I want to distinguish the big spot, which specific algorithm should I use ?

thank you for answer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, imho u should first go through all the tutorials at opencv website. Then you will be in a better position to tackle this problem. Also, try Digital Image Processing book by Gonzales & Woods

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comment, you should learn about basic image processing techniques. This being said, if you already know about image processing and just worded poorly your question, I would recommend either : a/ Canny (edge detection) + Hough Transform (circle detection) or b/ Canny + connectectedComponentsWithStats and use the stats to find out which shapes are circles